# Firebug 1.11.2 is not working on Mozilla Firefox 18.0.2

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, firebug

Right clicking "inspect element with firebug" used to show me the HTML content but suddenly it stopped. I removed it and installed Firebug 1.11.2 on Mozilla Firefox 18.0.2. Still "inspect element with firebug" shows nothing. I have user agent switcher and view cookies installed as well.
       Also, i cant do much without firebug in Firefox because in chrome the "Firebug Lite for Google Chrome™ 1.4.0.11967" does not give the option of edit HTML content. Hence it is not much useful. If only i can check HTML in Firefox. 
       I know that the problem is very specific, still anything would do...

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Firefox to version 19